# Когда удаляется static переменная в php?

Tags: php, pdo

Ранее объект для работы с БД создавался как глобальная переменная сразу в начале выполнения скрипта. Потом я переписал это в следующий вид.

```
class GlobalData {

    private static $DB = null;

    public static function getDB() {
        if(!GlobalData::$DB) {
            GlobalData::$DB = new DBProvider();
        }
        return GlobalData::$DB;
    }
}
```

Все вроде хорошо, только стали иногда на сайте появляться ошибки типа:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

и иногда

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections

Ранее (когда была просто глобальная переменная) такого не было. Внутри `DBProvider` используется PDO. Соединение вручную не закрывается в расчете на то, что оно будет закрыто автоматически по завершении работы скрипта.

Может ли быть данная проблема связана с новой архитектурой?

Comment: `self::$DB`, а не `GlobalData::$DB`.

Comment: Да, знаю. Только это поведение от этого не меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При завершении скрипта или если чем-то заменить статическую переменную. Сборщик мусора статические переменные никогда не трогает, т.к. не без оснований полагает, что к ней могут обратиться впоследствии.

Обе приведённые ошибки никак не связаны со статическими переменными, т.к. возникают при создании подключения, а не после.

`connection refused` - `mysql` отклонил соединение. Например, упёрлись в [back_log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_back_log). Некоторые пояснения от [`percona`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/01/06/mysql-high-number-connections-per-secon/). Или ОС отклонила соединение, там тоже лимиты есть, например упомянутый перконой `tcp_max_syn_backlog`.

`Too many connections` - соответственно, слишком много открытых соединений. Упёрлись в [max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections), есть отдельная страница [в мануале](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html).

Очевидно, вы немного выросли по посещаемости с тех пор, вот и перестало лимитов хватать. Смотрите в мониторинг.

Answer (score -1):

Это не связанные между собой события. Возможно у вас возросло количество пользователей, либо что-то с базой сделали. Или где-то в другом месте соединения плодятся.

Как вариант, используйте постоянные соединения

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

И еще, лучше делать явную проверку

```
if(self::$DB === null) {
```